# python package's hash not found in poetry.lock file

Tags: python-3.x, dependency-management, python-poetry, python-3.10

i have 2 python projects named `my-package` and `my-project`. `my-package` acts as a framework and is a dependency of `my-project`. I use `poetry` to manage dependencies and i host `my-package` on a private remote repository. Whenever i make new changes to the framework, i always make sure to bump the version number in it's `pyproject.toml` followed by a `poetry lock --no-update` and i will deploy this to my remote repo. Now, from inside `my-project`, i wish to pull the latest version of `my-package` so i perform `poetry update my-package` but am suddenly getting this error

```
❯ poetry update my-package
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (1.7s)

Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals

  • Updating my-package (0.0.9 -> 0.0.10): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Retrieved digest for link my-package-0.0.10.tar.gz(sha256:123abc) not in poetry.lock metadata {'sha256:456efg', 'sha256:789xyz'}

  at .venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:120 in _get_links
      116│ 
      117│             selected_links.append(link)
      118│ 
      119│         if links and not selected_links:
    → 120│             raise RuntimeError(
      121│                 f"Retrieved digest for link {link.filename}({h}) not in poetry.lock"
      122│                 f" metadata {hashes}"
      123│             )
      124│
```

what did i do wrong here and how do i fix this?

i am on python3.10 and poetry 1.61

Answer (score -1):

looks like i needed to clear my pypoetry cache with `poetry cache clear --all .`